# reactjs - adding friends to InnerCircle list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have a list of `friendsboxes` with each `friendsbox` a button that should add the friends assign to the `InnerCircle` list. In the `friendsDetail` component the `addToInnerCircle should add the friend's details to the` InnerCircle` list.

My first guess would be to add a `InnerCircle` array as part of my user model and then make this function addToInnerCircle add a inner circle member id on click of the button "add to inner circle". Afterwards I would do a `ComponentDidMount` in `Friends.js` and pull the data (+ store in state of `Friends.js` under InnerCircle) for every element of the InnerCircle Array for the logged in user and via Populate get to all the data for that specific person.

Does that make sense or is there a better approach in doing this?

**Friends.js**

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
    import './Friends.css'
    import Axios from 'axios'
    import Frienddetail from '../components/Frienddetail'
    import InnerCircleDetail from '../components/InnerCircleDetail'
    import { getUser } from '../utils/auth'
    
    class Friendsfollowers extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super()
            this.state = {
                friends: [],
                searchFriends: [],
                innerCircle: [],
                searchInnerCircle: []       
            }
            
            this.searchFriends=this.searchFriends.bind(this)
        }
    
        componentDidMount(){ 
            Axios({
                method: "GET",
                url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/friends`,
                withCredentials: true       
            })
            .then(response =>{
                console.log(response)
                let friendslist = response.data // eslint-disable-next-line
                let friendslistupdate = friendslist.filter(friend => {
                    if(friend.username){
                        if(friend.username !== getUser().username){
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                })
                this.setState({
                    friends:friendslistupdate,
                    searchFriends: friendslistupdate
                })
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log("Charles made an error when retrieving all friends: ",error)
            })
    }

        render() {
            return (
                <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="friendsoverviewcontainer">
                    <h1>Our community</h1>
                    <form className="friends">               
                        <div className="titlepart">
                            <label className="friendlabel" htmlFor="friend">Search for Users :</label><br></br>
                            <input className="friendform" type="text" name="friend" value={this.state.friend} placeholder="Type a username here!" onChange={this.searchFriends}></input>
                        </div>
                    </form>
    
                    <div className="friendsboxes" >
                        {
                            this.state.searchFriends.map(friend =>
                                <div key={friend._id}>
                                    <Frienddetail 
                                        key={friend._id}
                                        id={friend._id}
                                        username={friend.username}
                                        location={friend.location}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )   
                        }
                    </div>
                </div> 
    
                <div className="innercirclecontainer">
                    <h1>Your inner circle</h1>
                    <div className="innercircleboxes">
                        {
                            this.state.searchInnerCircle.map(inner =>
                                <div key={inner._id}>
                                    <InnerCircleDetail 
                                        key={inner._id}
                                        id={inner._id}
                                        username={inner.username}
                                        location={inner.location}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            )   
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Frienddetail.js**

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import './Frienddetail.css'
    
    class InnerCircleDetail extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super()
    
            this.state = {
                
            }
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                    <div className="friendbox">
                        <img className="imagedaredevilspicdetail" src="/images/profileimage.png" alt="picturesetting" />
                        <p className="friend">{this.props.username}</p>
                        <p className="friend">{this.props.location}</p>
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default InnerCircleDetail
```

Answer (score 0):

So you wouldn't need to do anything with componentDidMount since updating state with added ids in innerCircle wouldn't trigger a remount, but rather componentDidUpdate. To render the innerCircle you would just render a filtered version of friends where id must match an id within innerCircle.

Check out this working version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-http-gin2j?file=/src/ICDetail.js

```
{friends
    .filter(friend => innerCircle.some(id => id === friend.id))
    .map((friend, index) => {
        return (
           <ICDetail
              key={friend.id}
              friend={friend}
              removeFromIC={() => this.removeFromIC(index)}
           />
        );
   })
}
```

Comment: thanks that's helpful! Does my approach to add a InnerCircle array as part of my user model and then make this function addToInnerCircle add a inner circle member id on click of the button "add to inner circle" make sense?

Comment: Yes it does; as stated above you don't have to then " do a ComponentDidMount in Friends.js and pull the data (+ store in state of Friends.js under InnerCircle) for every element of the InnerCircle Array"; you can just use the ids directly to render a filtered version of friends.